# Type Error in Swift :Cannot convert value of type '[UInt64]' to expected argument type 'inout UInt64'

Tags: swift, swift4

New to Swift, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[UInt64]' to expected argument type 'inout UInt64'

I don't understand the "inout" *typing*

```
/// non crypto hash
func strHash(_ str: String) -> UInt64 {
    var result = UInt64 (5381)
    let buf = [UInt8](str.utf8)
    for b in buf {
        result = 127 * (result & 0x00ffffffffffffff) + UInt64(b)
    }
    return result
}

let myString: String = "Hello World"

let words = myString.components(separatedBy: " " )
print(words)
var hashArry = [UInt64]()
for w in words {
    hashArry += strHash(w) // <<<<<<<<< Here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot use `+=` as you might have expected. 
Use

```
hashArray.append(strHash(w))
```

instead. And do not wonder about the sometimes very confusing compiler error messages :-)

Comment: thanks!  I did see that method but didn't put 0b10 and 0b10 together!  appreciate the help!